# Post an array from Javascript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, post

I have an array in Javascript that i am trying to pass to php.  my array looks like this.

```
 Array[0]
   "empNo" : "1347"
   "empName" : "John Doe"
```

I am building this array from this javascript:

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function()
{
             if ($(this).attr("value").length>0)
             {
                  param[$(this).attr("id")]=$(this).attr("value");
             }            
});
```

Then I pass the array to php using

```
$.post("example.php",param)
```

Then in php when I try to interact with the post like this:

```
$emp=$_POST['empNo'];
$name=$_POST['empName'];
echo ($_GET[0]);//this is for testing
```

It throws an error saying that `The Indexes of empNo and empName are not Defined`.

It also says that `0 is an undefined offset`.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Your problem is either in Javascript or PHP and your first step should be to figure out which one.  Use Firebug net tab to determine if the POST is being made correctly, then work back or forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of looping through and manually building your data to pass just do this for the whole form.

```
var data = $('form').serialize();

$.post("example.php", data);
```

Then you should have access as you expect in your php script.

**BUT** make sure you're using the `<input name="exampleName" />` attribute and then try to access them like this...

```
$value = $_POST['exampleName'];
```

while right now, it looks like you're trying to use the `id` instead of `name`

Comment: yep i switched to serialize and it is working now.  thanks for the switching to the name value tip.  it is working now.  Thanks!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that $_POST has an array whose members are the values you are sending.

So, I think the values are in $_POST[1], $_POST[2], etc...

Try to print_r($_POST) and see where your variables went to.

Response to your comment:

I would tidy up things a bit, just a suggestion - especially the attr('value') part.

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function() {
     if ( $(this).val() ) { 
         param[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
     }            
});
```

Comment: when i do a print_r($_POST) all i got was array()

Comment: That means your post variable aren't being set. I'd use serialize as is suggested above or use a string method "param1=value&param2=value2" etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var param = $('form').serialize();

$.post("example.php", param);
```

Comment: Note that it won't work unless you've set the `name`s of the inputs appropriately. Use names not IDs.